# How to install Canon LBP-6000 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon

I have canon LBP-6000 printer. I have installed driver downloading from https://www.canon.com.au/support/sims-content?pid=53e6ba4b31b440c190460e8ecaf74948&cid=680588CF44C34B76A9E96CF1C8935376&ctype=dr . I have added printer from printer setting. But when I print something then these message appear "Printing" and "printing completed". 
But printer is not printing anything. What's the problem? What have I to do?

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) to manage printers and print queues. Point your web browser to the CUPS admin page, http://localhost:631 [image: CUPS Admin Page] and click on "`Find New Printers`". Respond with your login ID and password when prompted.

As for the vanishing print job, check your default printer with `lpstat -d`, and look at the logs in `/var/log/cups/*`.